# Unable to build Linux kernel module out of static driver code

Tags: linux-kernel, drivers, compiling, kernel-modules

I am trying to build a kernel module (`.ko`) out of a driver that doesn't have module configuration by default. I want to avoid having a built-in driver because I get firmware loading errors.

I did the following,

1. `Bt_driver.c`:

   ```
   module_int(BT_Driver_init);
   module_exit(BT_Driver_deinit);
   ```
2. Menuconfig:

   ```
   obj-$(CONFIG_BT_DRI) := Bt_driver.o
   ```
3. Kconfig:

   ```
   tristate "Bt Module " // So, I can select Y, N and M option
   ```
4. defconfig

   ```
   CONFIG_BT_DRI=m
   ```

After the build was done, I didn't find a `Bt_driver.ko` module in the build location.

Comment: Thank you @Bodo for editing

Comment: Without more details we cannot guess what's wrong. Please [edit] your question and show the commands that get executed when you try to build your module and the corresponding output or error message(s)

Answer (score 0):

After adding `module_init()` and `module_exit()` you may need to add the module license:
`MODULE_LICENSE("GPL")`, for example.

Unless the module will not be built (tainted).

If its still not building the loadable module kernel, try to build using your own Makefile (for this module).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).